# How to get the statistics of binary matrix?

Tags: r

I have a very big binary matrix (0,1). I'm interested to know the minimum/maximum and average number of 1s (non-zero elements in a row) in rows.
Would someone help me to compute it?

For example for matrix A would be :

```
    > A
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    1    0    1
    [2,]    0    0    0    1
    [3,]    1    1    0    0
    > 
min : 1
max: 3
average:2
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean a `summary` of the `rowSums`?

```
> set.seed(154)
> A <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 80, TRUE), 8, 10)
> A
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     0
## [2,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0     1
## [3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1     0
## [4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1     0
## [5,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0     0
## [6,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    1     0
## [7,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
## [8,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
> summary(rowSums(A))[c('Min.', 'Max.', 'Mean')]
## Min. Max. Mean 
## 4.00 9.00 6.25
```